# MSIE and addEventListener Problem in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, addeventlistener

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('copy',beforecopy,false );
```

In Chrome / Safari, the above will run the "beforecopy" function when the content on the page is being copied. MSIE is supposed to support this functionality as well, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Now, it's my understanding that Internet Explorer won't play with the body node, but I would have thought providing a node by ID would work fine. Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

** Bonus points for anyone who can tell me what the 3rd parameter "False" is good for.

Comment: Here is a good article that explains the capture phase and `useCapture` very well: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/12/an-introduction-to-dom-events/#event-phases

Answer (score 186, accepted):

In IE you have to use [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx) rather than the standard [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

A common practice is to check if the `addEventListener` method is available and use it, otherwise use `attachEvent`:

```
if (el.addEventListener){
  el.addEventListener('click', modifyText, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent){
  el.attachEvent('onclick', modifyText);
}
```

You can make a function to do it:

```
function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
  if (el.addEventListener){
    el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false); 
  } else if (el.attachEvent){
    el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
  }
}
// ...
bindEvent(document.getElementById('myElement'), 'click', function () {
  alert('element clicked');
});
```

You can run an example of the above code [here](http://jsbin.com/ifuqa).

The third argument of `addEventListener` is `useCapture`; if true, it indicates that the user wishes to initiate [event capturing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Comment: I appreciate your response. I just tried what you posted, and it worked. The thing that's throwing me off now is that the "copy" event isn't working but the "onclick" event is. Specifically, this is strange because quirksmode states that it should work:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Scratch that comment. I just isolated and tried what you sent, and changing click to copy does work. Thanks again.

Comment: why does microsoft's own documentation show using `addEventListener` then? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197015(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @wmarbut addEventListener was added in, I believe, IE9. attachEvent was removed in IE 11. The original question is from 2009. CMS has provided the correct, robust method that continues to work even with IE 11.

Comment: That explains why it works on the internet but not on the intranet for me, because I have my settings for intranet sites set to compatibility mode.

Answer (score 33):

In case you are using JQuery 2.x then please add the following in the

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;" />
   </head>
   <body>
    ...
   </body>
</html>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: for those that run IE versions <= 8, this will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Internet Explorer (IE8 and lower) doesn't support [`addEventListener(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). It has its own event model using the [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) method. You could use some code like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('container');
if (document.addEventListener){
    element .addEventListener('copy', beforeCopy, false); 
} else if (el.attachEvent){
    element .attachEvent('oncopy', beforeCopy);
}
```

Though I recommend avoiding writing your own event handling wrapper and instead use a JavaScript framework (such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/), etc) and avoid having to create the fix for this on your own.

By the way, the third argument in the W3C model of events has to do with the [difference between bubbling and capturing events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). In almost every situation you'll want to handle events as they bubble, not when they're captured. It is useful when using [event delegation](http://icant.co.uk/sandbox/eventdelegation/) on things like "focus" events for text boxes, which don't bubble.

Answer (score 5):

try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

right after the opening head tag

Comment: for those that run IE versions <= 8, this will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As of IE11, you need to use `addEventListener`. `attachEvent` is deprecated and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE does not have the standard `addEventListener` method. IE uses its own `attachEvent` which does pretty much the same.

Good explanation of the differences, and also about the 3rd parameter can be found [at quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Answer (score 0):

As PPK points out [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9), in IE you can also use

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`, IE9+ does support `addEventListener` by removing the "on" in the event name, like this:

```
 var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
 btn1.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
   console.log('mousedown');
 });
```