# IE8: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I know that my issue is known, I just can't figure out a way to fix the problem.
However the code works in chrome,ff and safari, but not in ie6-8.
I tried to debug the code and following popped up:
*Line: 272
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method*

This is line 272 from my js-file

```
$('#page1')[0].addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', self.webkitAnimationEnd, true);
```

Hav you got an idea what is wrong with it? I'm using jquery     `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js">;</script>` which is called in my .html file.

I appreciate any help or useful hint.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: IE doesn't support `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) for IE here is a SO link [MSIE and addEventListener Problem in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript/1695383#1695383)

your code may look like

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
$('#page1')[0].attachEvent('webkitAnimationEnd', self.webkitAnimationEnd);
}
```

hope that will help

Answer (score 5):

[See mozilla docs for problem description and solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer)

```
var el = $('#page1')[0];
if (el.addEventListener){
  el.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', self.webkitAnimationEnd, true);
} else if (el.attachEvent){
  el.attachEvent('webkitAnimationEnd', self.webkitAnimationEnd);
}
```