# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'removeEventListener' in IE8 only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following strip down page. It works perfectly fine in other browsers except IE8. Not sure why IE8 is throwing SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'removeEventListener' jquery-1.9.1.js, line 109 character 4
I tried to remove the references but sometimes it stops throwing error after removing svg.js or sometime after tiny_mce. Any idea why IE8 is throwing this error.

```
<script src="javascript/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery/jquery-ui.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
<script src="javascript/svgweb/svg.js" data-path="javascript/svgweb"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<style>
.bannerbar_background{
    float:left; 
top:0px;
    left:0px;
background-image:url(images/icons/bannerbar_background.png); background-repeat:    repeat-x;
height:100px;
width:100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>  
    <div class="bannerbar_background">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: IE8 doesn't support `addEventListener` or `removeEventListener`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531462/ie8-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method).  Something is trying to use it.

Comment: it should be fine.... if jQury 1.x version is used.... but for jQuery >= 2.x versions support for IE < 9 was removed.... so please verify that the jQuery file is a 1.x version by opening it

Comment: Yes, the file I am using is 1.9.1 version. Now I found if I removed the background-image path from bannerbar_background class, it does not throws any error.. Not sure if that make any sense :(