# changing backgroundColor using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

This script works fine in all other browsers except IE:

```
nav.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e) {
        switch(e.target.id) {
            case 'aGallery':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            break;
            case 'aContact':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            break;
            case 'aAbout':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            break;
            case 'aHome':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "#CC33CC";
            break;
        }
    },false);
```

In IE, the backgroundcolor does not change on hover.

Any ideas?

Comment: If possible, I recommend using jQuery.  It takes care of issues like this for you, making it work the same in most browsers, including IE.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE you have to use `attachEvent` rather than the standard `addEventListener`. And use `srcElement` instead of `target` for IE.

Try this.

```
function mouseOverHandler(e) {
        switch((e.target || e.srcElement).id) {
            case 'aGallery':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            break;
            case 'aContact':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            break;
            case 'aAbout':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            break;
            case 'aHome':
            navOpacity.style.backgroundColor = "#CC33CC";
            break;
        }
}

if (el.addEventListener){
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOverHandler, false); 
} 
else if (el.attachEvent){
  el.attachEvent('onmouseover', mouseOverHandler);
}
```

Comment: Some day, we should all get together and form some sort of committee to make browser standards!  And all the browsers can follow them!

Answer (score 1):

IE uses the 'on' versions for events, line `onclick`, `onmouseover`. There should be your problem.

Also, IE (prior to version 9), does not support `addEventListener`. You must use `attachEvent`.

Consider this code as a starting point:

```
if (el.addEventListener){
  el.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
} else if (el.attachEvent){
  el.attachEvent('onclick', myFunc);
}
```

Comment: Another problem is IE uses `event.srcElement` instead of the W3C standard `target` property.