# using window.location with a simple html link

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

Trying to make a **simple** HTML page with a some links on it, but trying to make it so it detects you are either local or using the SSH Port Forwarding.

Some info;

URL I use when accessing the webpage Locally : 192.168.3.5/www/index.html

URL I Use when Using SSH Port Forwarding : 127.0.0.1:9009/www/index.html

This is the full code I am using in my index.html page....

```
<HTML>
- SABNZBD : Pick <A href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.port=8080">LOCAL</a> or <A href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.port=9001">REMOTE</a> Connection.
</HTML>
```

If I use this code;

```
 onclick="javascript:window.location.port=9001"
```

It sort of works, it returns

```
http://127.0.0.1:9001/www/#
```

I really want it to return just this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:9001/
```

Is there a way I could use the below code ?  So it strips the pathname and just uses the hostname and the portname that I have specified ? As I can't seem to get it to work.

```
onclick="javascript:window.location.hostname && window.location.port=9001"
```

Thx
Matt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you need, when concatenating strings you should use `+` not `&&`

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + 
   '//' + window.location.hostname + ':9001';
```

You can use the above in an `onclick` handler:

```
onclick="window.location = ..."
```

You don't need to specify `onclick="javascript:"` as this is assumed by default.

Also, rather than using inline click handlers, it would be better to use the following:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For how to use both the above together *(addEventListener for the modern browsers, attachEvent for IE)*:

- [MSIE and addEventListener Problem in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript)

Or if you wanted to make life simpler you could just use a JavaScript library that handles these browser differences automatically. Like jQuery.

```
$('.class_on_first_link').click(function(){
  window.location = window.location.protocol + 
   '//' + window.location.hostname + ':8080';
});

$('.class_on_second_link').click(function(){
  window.location = window.location.protocol + 
   '//' + window.location.hostname + ':9001';
});
```

#### update

What I meant by the ellipsis above was:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location = window.location.protocol + 
   '//' + window.location.hostname + ':9001';">Port 9001</a>
<a href="#" onclick="window.location = window.location.protocol + 
   '//' + window.location.hostname + ':8080';">Port 8080</a>
```

Comment: How would I put that into an HTML file,<BR>

    `<HTML>
    <SCRIPT>
     window.location = window.location.protocol + 
      '//' + window.location.hostname + ':9001';
    </SCRIPT>
    SABNZBD : <A href="#" onclick="window.location = ...">REMOTE</a>  Connection.
    </HTML>`

??

Anyway to have it so that the onclick specifies the port number?

Comment: Sorry about above, new to stack... here is a more readable version, [PasteBin Code](http://pastebin.com/qDBc0QWD)

Comment: @Matt I've updated my answer with a response to what you've asked. Rather than using pastebin, in future, just update your question with further information. Welcome to SO btw :)

Comment: BINGO, thx for that works nicely now. Will remember the tip about updating code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `pathname` as well should do the trick

```
onclick="window.location.port=9001;window.location.pathname='/'"
```

Comment: I like this, but no luck, doesn't seem to add the port.