# Drowdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

I've got a dropdown menu made with javascript but it doesn't work in IE while working good in Firefox and Chrome. The HTML code I'm using is this:

```
<div id="sidemeny-container">
<div class="sidemenu-maincat">
    <img src="cat1.jpg" alt="cat1" />
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat1.html"> - Subcat 1 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2.html"> - Subcat 2 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat3.html"> - Subcat 3 </a>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="sidemenu-maincat">
    <img src="cat2.jpg" alt="cat2" />
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2-1.html"> - Subcat 2-1 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2-2.html"> - Subcat 2-2 </a>
        </div>
        <div class="sidemenu-subcat hidden">
        <a href="subcat2-3.html"> - Subcat 2-3 </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#sidemeny-container {
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid; 
    height: auto;
    width: 153px;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.sidemenu-maincat {
    border-top: 1px #000 solid;
    border-right: 1px #000000 solid;
    width:148px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.sidemenu-subcat.hidden {
    display:none;
    width:148px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

And the javascript

```
  function initiate()
{

var sideMenuOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-maincat');
    for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
        sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');
    for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
      var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
      if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
        subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
      } else {
        subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
      }
    }
  });
    }       
}

window.onload = initiate;
```

I can't understand why this won't work in IE since it's working so good in the other browsers. And I prefer to keep all my javascript in my separate document javascript.js as well as I don't want to work with a library.

Comment: for IE, you should use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`

Comment: Working in IE9 but not in IE8 it seems, do you want it to work in IE8?

Comment: Check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript

Comment: I think getElementsByClassName is also not supported in IE

Comment: thats correct ...but Only in IE8 and below...

Comment: use the template and append the data into it

Comment: @RahulR. I'm pretty new to javascript and I don't really understand how I remake the code in that way, do you mind specifying a bit more?

Comment: So there are equivalent functions in IE for these non supported functions and you need to use them if browser is IE. the code given by  @Stephan Zaria will be replaced with your one line of code i.e. linevar subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');

and almost same you have to do for addEventListener, take help of question i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName is not supported by IE. The easiest way to overcome this, without using libraries, is to use document.getElementsByTagName, loop over the results, and check each result's classname. Something like:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName)
    {
        var sideMenuOptions = document.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-maincat');
        for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
            sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                var subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');
                for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
                    var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
                    if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
                        subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
                    } else {
                        subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var sideMenuOptions = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var i = 0; i < sideMenuOptions.length; i++) {
            if (sideMenuOptions[i].className == 'sidemenu-maincat')
            {
                sideMenuOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var subMenuItems = this.getElementsByClassName('sidemenu-subcat');
                    for (var s = 0; s < subMenuItems.length; s++) {
                        var subItem = subMenuItems[s];
                        if (subItem.offsetWidth === 0 && subItem.offsetHeight === 0) {
                            subItem.className = 'sidemenu-subcat';
                        } else {
                            subItem.className = subItem.className + ' hidden';
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I put it into my function initiate(). Is that the correct way I should do it?