# A variable that holds coordinates of last mouse click only

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent

This is what I'm trying to accomplish. I want an item to show up on the screen at the last position the mouse had clicked. Currently it sort of works, but every time I click elsewhere the said item moves there as well. I just want it to be static.

Here's some code:

global variables px and py. Used to hold mouse clicks:

```
private int px = 250; // initial coordinates
private int py = 250;
```

mouse clicks feed global px and py:

```
private void testPress(int x, int y) {
    if (!isPaused && !gameOver) {
        // do something..
        px = x;
        py = y;
        girlP.setDestination((px-(girlP.getImage().getWidth(this)/2)), 
                (py-(girlP.getImage().getHeight(this)/2)));

        //System.out.println(px + ", " + py);
    }
}
```

There px and py are constantly updated with new values. What I want is a way to only hold the last mouse click

Comment: You want it at the last clicked position, but not to move when you click? Your question doesn't make sense at the moment.

Comment: @keppil Yeah it is kind of confusing. Basically, I have a character that moves to wherever the mouse specifies. The character is to have the ability to plant flowers. What I want to do plant a flower wherever the character is standing (i.e. the last mouse point).

Comment: For one, you need to define some kind of 'pinning' action - aka, what distinguishes between a mouse click that should 'pin' your item to a spot, vs a mouse click that shouldn't. Also, you shouldn't use global state unless you expect to only ever have the one item that will behave as described.

Comment: @Perception What if I used an array somehow?

Comment: @blutuu - I don't see how an array will help with what is a more fundamental design problem. Now, if you wanted to store a history of clicked locations, then yea, storing points in a (size-bounded) array would be ok, but that doesn't address the original issue, which is - 'whats the difference between a click that pins and a click that doesnt'? As an example of a possible solution, you could define right clicks to pin, and left clicks to do 'whatever else'.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript) to understand how to listen for mouse events

You can use `event.clickX` and `event.clickY` to get the coordinates within the element you listen for mouse click on, or use `event.screenX` and `event.screenY` to get the absolute mouse coordinates within the document.