# Remove Javascript generated HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm currently learning Javascript by making a simple to-do list. I would like to know how to remove HTML content once it has been generated by Javascript. If the user pressed the `'x'` between the `<span>` tags, it would then delete that item:

```
    var doc = document;

    function addText(){

    var input = doc.getElementById('input').value;
    doc.getElementById('do').innerHTML += "<li>" + input + " <span> x </span>" + "</li>";

  }
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<input type='text' id='input' />
<input type='button' onclick='addText()' value='Add' />
</form>

<ul id="do"> </ul>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/jsnrw/)

Comment: This is what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are learning JavaScript, and looking at your code and accepted answer, you should take care of the following 3 things:

> **A**.  Don't use `innerHTML` for adding **single** DOM elements.

In your code you are doing a `....innerHTML += ...`, which means the full `innerHTML` is re-marked-up and inserted every time.

Meaning, for 10th `li`, you are adding 10 items. For 11th `li`, you are removing the 10 and then adding 11 items, instead of 1. Its bad for `DOM` performance, and doesn't make sense to add all the `li`s again for every `li` inserted.

`innerHTML` is good for one time operation.

> **B**. Never use inline JavaScript!

It has tons of reasons. Besides, other developers in the community hate it. And looking on a question that uses it, they would run away.

`<span onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)' >`

This is Bad, Bad, Very Bad!

> **C**. Use **Event Delegation**!

Look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/1249219).

In short, instead of having multiple click functions for every `li`, its better to have a single function on `ul`. If you click an `li` you are also clicking the `ul`. One can check which `li` was clicked in the `ul` and then remove it as follows:

---

**HTML**:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='input' />
    <input type='button' id='add-btn' value='Add' />
</form>
<ul id="do"> </ul>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var doc = document,
    parentUL = document.getElementById('do'),
    addBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {    
    var input = doc.getElementById('input').value,
        li = doc.createElement('li');

    // use innerHTML only to set the conetnt of single DOM item
    li.innerHTML = input + '<span style="cursor: pointer; color: red; margin-left: 20px" > x </span>';

    // append only once on every create
    parentUL.appendChild(li);
});

// delegate UL's click to li, by checking target item
parentUL.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    // check the real target
    var target = evt.target,
        liNode = target.parentNode;
    parentUL.removeChild(liNode);
});
```

Note: `addEventListener` is for modern browsers only. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695383/1249219) for cross browser thingy.
Collectively all this might seem an overhead for your previous small code, but this is a good practice that will save the world and JavaScript.
Although you have accepted the answer, I have updated the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/OMS_/Qe2Z2/) with above code

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'
```

Such as:

```
doc.getElementById('do').innerHTML += "<li>" + input + " <span onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)' > x </span>" + "</li>";
```

**[Your fiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/jsnrw/4/)**

**Note:** I also added the `cursor: pointer` CSS, so the `x` make some sense to the user.