# setTimeout doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I have made a div with id "about" with *display:none* and I wrote this script :

```
function showbox() {
    document.getElementById('about').style.display="block"
};
```

And added the function as an event to another div :

```
<div class="button" onClick="slide();setTimeout(showbox(),3000)">About</div>
```

So that when the user click on the div with class "button" the div with id "about" will appear after 3 seconds, the code works with the showing part but it doesn't delay anything !
Note: the function slide() exists and works perfectly and it's not interfering with anything so don't question it.

Please tell me what's wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout(showbox,3000)`

Comment: The parenthesis here `setTimeout(showbox()...` invokes the function immediately.

Comment: You shouldn't use inline javascript like that.

Comment: I hope the 3 seconds timer is just for testing purposes because it's terrible design to let an user click a button and not give feedback on purpose before 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showbox` is all you need. Remove the `()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
// You are *calling* showbox() here -- not passing the function ref as a parameter.
// Use this instead.

<div class="button" onClick="slide();setTimeout(showbox,3000)">About</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using code comments like that?

Comment: It just came out that way --  I carry over from when I do leave comments like this in real code I'm passing back to someone.

Comment: then you should have used `<!-- comment -->` this is in the HTML after all ;)

Comment: -1 for advocating inline JS events.  There are better solutions, please teach them.

Answer (score 3):

Better methodology: separation of concerns. Inline javascript is bad practice. Just us an event listener!

```
var element; //grab element however you want
element.addEventListener("click",function() {
    slide();
    setTimeout(showbox,3000);
},false);
```

As the others said, you need to pass a function *reference* to the timeout. Having the `()` immediately calls the function.

Comment: On the other hand, addEventListener is not supported on all browsers (unlike inline calls). Edit: see topics like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript

Comment: It's supported back to IE9. For 8 and below, you use `attachEvent`. You could also use `element.onclick = function() { }` but that only allows one event to be attached.

Comment: @vdavid inline calls is simply bad JavaScript. It's ugly, hard to read, and the quotes can be a real pain. It's just no good.

Comment: I agree, but addEventListener is not an ideal solution either and is sometimes even worse since it can fail where inline would succeed.

Comment: @vdavid I literally teach JavaScript as one of my day jobs.  I disagree.  One should never use inline JS events.

Comment: @vdavid if you really have a valid need for that compatibility you would be better off using jQuery or something similar. Otherwise you'll be running into this kind of thing a lot. The browsers are deprecated so new code shouldn't cater to them.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 I must disagree with you on that point. Which is more meaningful: `<button>What do I do?</button>` or `<button onClick="turnOffTheInternet();">Oh right, probably better not to click me...</button>`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol meaningful?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You haven't heard of 'separation of concerns', have you?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 I have, and my concern is with keeping things that work together, together. Seeing the function name in the button, I can very easily Ctrl+F through my JS files to find the function and work on it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it's just as easy to inspect the element and find out what events are attached. Or to track down by id, name, class, or even by tag. It's not hard at all with Ctrl+F

Comment: @RUJordan Granted. Actually my projects tend to defer a lot of events so there's rarely a handler on a single element, and I have a custom `addEvent` function to manage both browser compatibility and allow easier detaching of events by using a named reference instead of keeping track of the callback.