# addEventListener not supporting in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have tried the below code for one of my project. This function performs unchecking the radio buttons on clicking another one. This code works in FF and chrome but not in iE. Please advice.

JS:

```
document.getElementById("main2").addEventListener("change", function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var subs_list = document.getElementsByName("main_sub");
        var subs = Array.prototype.slice.call(subs_list);
        subs.forEach(function(sub){
            sub.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

var subs_list_2 = document.getElementsByName("main_sub");
var subs_2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(subs_list_2);
subs_2.forEach(function(sub){
    sub.addEventListener("change", function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            document.getElementById("main2").checked = false;
            document.getElementById("main").checked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, `addEventListener` doesn't work in IE8. I'd just use jQuery, keep it simple. `forEach` doesn't work either FYI.

Comment: Load a project using conditional comments that patches IE8, and you're set. Like this: [ES5-DOM-SHIM](https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM). That way you're not boxed into jQuery's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 does not support `addEventListener()`.  It has it's own `attachEvent()` which is similar so you have to check if `addEventListener` is there and if not, use `attachEvent()`.

IE8 also does not support `.forEach()` on arrays.  You can either install a shim (shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) for it or use a regular `for` loop to iterate through arrays (the old fashioned way).

This is a simple cross browser event function:

```
// add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            return(fn.call(elem, window.event));   
        });
    }
}
```

So, instead of:

```
sub.addEventListener("change", fn);
```

You would use this:

```
addEvent(sub, "change", fn);
```

and it would work in both modern browsers and older versions of IE>

Here's a little more advanced version with more features:

```
// refined add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    // allow the passing of an element id string instead of the DOM elem
    if (typeof elem === "string") {
        elem = document.getElementById(elem);
    }

    function listenHandler(e) {
        var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (ret === false) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    function attachHandler() {
        // normalize the target of the event
        window.event.target = window.event.srcElement;
        // make sure the event is passed to the fn also so that works the same too
        // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
        var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);   
        // support an optional return false to be cancel propagation and prevent default handling
        // like jQuery does
        if (ret === false) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        return(ret);
    }

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want me to just add the above code.? Or i have to rewrite the code?

Comment: You have to use the `addEvent()` function for adding event handlers instead of `obj.addEventListener()`. I added an example of usage to my answer.

Comment: Can you please help to rewrite my code by using attach event?

Comment: @user3589255 - I added an example of one of your event handlers to my answer.  Please look at that, look at what the `addEvent()` function does and then ask any more specific questions.

Comment: I did. 
How do i replace the below line?

document.getElementById("main2").addEventListener("change", function(){

Comment: @user3589255 - You would do it like this: `addEvent(document.getElementById("main2"), "change", function() {});`

Comment: @user3589255 - note that you will also have to fix the usage of `.forEach()` which is also not supported in IE8.  I added to my answer with a couple options for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Also, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1695383/1732875) for an answer, which is posted above.

This is also a good answer, link [here](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/2415137).