# Modernizr.load doesn't load my resources

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I have a question about the Modernizr.load routine that I can't get to work. This is my code:

```
Modernizr.load([
        {
            //CDN reference provided by http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-javascript-fallback-methods/ | Jake Rocheleau
            load: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
            complete: function () {
                if (!window.jQuery) {
                    Modernizr.load('JavaScript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');
                }
            }
        },
        {
            load: [
                'JavaScript/jquery.queryloader2.js',
                'JavaScript/jquery.easings.min.js',
                'JavaScript/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
                'JavaScript/jquery.fullpage.js'
            ],
            complete: function () {
                jQuery.noConflict(); // Block any conflicting jQuery markup from killing the workbench

                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    /*
                    DOM Event attachment fix (adjustment made to attachEvent by removing the 'on'-prefix to eventName)
                    There must be a better way to bind events with prefixes?
                    Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1695383/3305017
                    */
                    function bindDOMEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
                        if (el.addEventListener) {
                            el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
                        } else if (el.attachEvent) {
                            el.attachEvent(eventName, eventHandler);
                        }
                    }

                    bindDOMEvent(window, 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                        $('body').queryLoader2({
                            percentage: true
                        });
                    });

                    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                        verticalCentered: true,
                        resize: false,
                        slidesColor: [''],
                        anchors: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide', 'thirdSlide', 'fourthSlide'],
                        scrollingSpeed: 700,
                        easing: 'easeInQuart',
                        menu: false,
                        navigation: true,
                        navigationPosition: 'right',
                        navigationTooltips: ['', '', '', ''],
                        slidesNavigation: true,
                        slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
                        loopBottom: false,
                        loopTop: false,
                        loopHorizontal: false,
                        autoScrolling: true,
                        scrollOverflow: true,
                        css3: true,
                        paddingTop: '0',
                        paddingBottom: '0',
                        fixedElements: '#element1, .element2',
                        normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
                        keyboardScrolling: true,
                        touchSensitivity: 15,
                        continuousVertical: false,
                        animateAnchor: true,
                        //events
                        onLeave: function (index, direction) {
                            if (index == 3) {
                                $('.progressBarList').each(function () {
                                    progressBar(100, $(this).find('.progressBar'));
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
                            if (index == 3) {
                                $('.progressBarList').each(function () {
                                    progressBar($(this).find('.perc').html().replace('%', ''), $(this).find('.progressBar'));
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        afterRender: function () {
                            $('#scroll-navigation').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                        },
                        afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) { },
                        onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction) { }
                    });

                    $.unbindall = function () {
                        jQuery('*').unbind();
                    };

                    // Kill memory leaks
                    $(document).unload(function () {
                        jQuery.unbindall();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
```

When I view the console in Firebug I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).fullpage is not a function. [url]/jquery.fullpage.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 20ms]

What am I missing? Why are the resources not loading at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to verify the directory location of the file `jquery.fullpage.js`

the error 404 indicates that this file is not found...

Comment: Wow mate, I just figured it out by this guidance I'd forgotten that I'd downloaded a minified version of fullpage but forgotten to rename it in the resources... now I head on to the next problem. :)