# TEdgeBrowser for Delphi 10.4.1 and later: How to trap F12 (OpenDevToolsWindow)?

Tags: delphi, devtools, tedgebrowser

I am using `TEdgeBrowser` in Delphi 10.4.1.  It works very well.

The only nagging issue is, when `TEdgeBrowser` has focus, it grabs <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+C</kbd> and presents the OpenDevToolsWindow.  This is great, except I want to change some of the topmost properties of the Form before it loads (otherwise, the DevTools window will be behind the MainForm).

Is there any way to trap <kbd>F12</kbd> from the parent MainForm?  I have tried Application and MainForm key captures, but both fail to capture the `TEdgeBrowser` key events (when `TEdgeBrowser` has focus).

```
procedure TMainForm.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.Message of
    WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP:
      begin
      if Msg.WParam = VK_F11 then
         begin
         SetStatusLog(EID_KEYPRESS,'F11');
         Handled := true;
         end
      else if Msg.WParam = VK_F12 then
         begin
{ do something here and consider F12 handled, preventing F12 from going to TEdgeBrowser???}
         SetStatusLog(EID_KEYPRESS,'F12');
         Handled := true;
         end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Is there another way to tackle this?

Additionally, can I launch the OpenDevToolsWindow programmably?

Comment: With `ExecuteScript` (JS) you can insert JavaScript in the browser and also execute it. In this way you can place an EventListener.  Example _without the bracket <script> </script>_ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241258/microsoft-edge-keydown-eventhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241258/microsoft-edge-keydown-event) describes one for KeyDown. You have to return the key value to Delphi from JavaScript with `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` (Key) (that's the theory). To do this, you have to connect the WebMessageReceived event in Delphi.

Comment: @USauter The link you provided seems to be broken. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241258/microsoft-edge-keydown-event)

Comment: I can easily connect a post message in an ExecuteScript.  I tested this and it worked well with the WebMessageReceived event.  Unfortunately,  I cannot seem to use the recommended solution because it requires changes to the page code.  I would like to point EdgeBrowser to any site and still have control over keypress.  It seems I would need to change a page element.  Maybe I am misunderstanding the solution though.

Comment: Read about the AcceleratorKeyPressed event in Webview. Has anyone attempted to capture this event?

Comment: If you want to add a listener with Javascript, I recommend considering using the AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreated rather than ExecuteScript.  This function is part of the TEdgeBrowser.DefaultInterface interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used two ways to handle this.  (1) You can call Set_AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled(0) to disable the browser's accelerator keys (but that might include disabling more than you want, and that is not really what you asked.)  And it requires some additional work to get access to this interface as it is not included in the current TEdgeBrowser.  Also, I read somewhere that the AcceleratorKey event still fires, even if you disable them in the EdgeBrowser so if you use that approach, you can process them.  (2) Use the AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreated to inject some Javascript that can prevent the default behavior (if desired) and send your app a message (which you'll pick up on OnWebMessageReceived) so you can process the event.

Option 1:

You'll need to define the following to get access to the interfaces you need as they were introduced after what TEdgeBrowser has:

```
const
  IID_ICoreWebview2Settings2: TGUID = '{EE9A0F68-F46C-4E32-AC23-EF8CAC224D2A}'; //Introduced: SDK  1.0.864.35
  IID_ICoreWebview2Settings3: TGUID = '{FDB5AB74-AF33-4854-84F0-0A631DEB5EBA}'; //Introduced: SDK  1.0.864.35

type
  ICoreWebView2Settings2 = interface(ICoreWebView2Settings)
    ['{EE9A0F68-F46C-4E32-AC23-EF8CAC224D2A}']
    function Get_UserAgent(out UserAgent: PWideChar): HResult; stdcall;
    function Set_UserAgent(UserAgent: PWideChar): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  ICoreWebView2Settings3 = interface(ICoreWebView2Settings2)
    ['{FDB5AB74-AF33-4854-84F0-0A631DEB5EBA}']
    function Get_AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled(out AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    function Set_AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled(AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
  end;
```

Then in your OnCreateWebViewCompleted event you can do

```
var
  Settings3: ICoreWebView2Settings3;
  HR: HRESULT;
begin
  Sender.SettingsInterface.QueryInterface(IID_ICoreWebView2Settings3, Settings3);
  if Assigned(Settings3) then
  begin
    HR := Settings3.Set_AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled(0);
    if not SUCCEEDED(HR) then
      {Do something - Set_AreBrowserAcceleratorKeysEnabled failed};
  end
  else
    {Do something - ICoreWebView2Settings3 interface not found.};
  end;
```

Option 2:

In your OnCreateWebViewCompleted event you can do the following

```
const
  JavaScript =
    '  document.addEventListener(''keydown'', function(event){' + sLineBreak +
    '    if (event.code == "F12") {' + sLineBreak +
    '      Result = "#KEY_EVENT#" + event.code;' + sLineBreak +
    '      event.preventDefault();' + sLineBreak +
    '      window.chrome.webview.postMessage(Result);' + sLineBreak +
    '    };' + sLineBreak +
    '  });'; 

{...}                                                                       
begin
  Sender.DefaultInterface.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreated(JavaScript,
    Callback<HResult, PChar>.CreateAs<ICoreWebView2AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedCompletedHandler>(
    function(ErrorCode: HResult; Id: PWideChar): HResult stdcall
    begin
      if not(Succeeded(ErrorCode)) then
        {Do something if this function failed.  It gets called later when a document id created.  Or you can pass nil for the Callback};
      Result := 1;
    end));
```

Note, in Option 2, see TEdgeBrowser code as example for defining the Callback.  It is defined in the implementation part of TEdgeBrowser.  I just replicated it in my own form's unit implementation section.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  Your solution works well.  I am able to disable all kesy and/or enable them at my discretion.   This followup is a bit unrelated.  Can I reroute console log entries to a delphi handler as well?

Comment: Glad you got it working.  I don't know about rerouting console log entries, but I forgot to mention, you can open the DevToolsWindow programmatically with something like EdgeBrowser1.DefaultInterface.OpenDevToolsWindow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ASender.DevToolsEnabled := False;`
in the `OnCreateWebViewCompleted` event

Comment: This works for me and seems to be the most easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

@stackman

> I cannot seem to use the recommended solution because it requires changes to the page code. I would like to point EdgeBrowser to any site and still have control over keypress.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
{$J+}
const
  STEP: integer = 1;
var
 Js: string;
begin
  case STEP of
    1: web.CreateWebView;
    2: web.Navigate('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70089520/tedgebrowser-for-delphi-10-4-1-and-later-how-to-trap-f12-opendevtoolswindow?noredirect=1#comment123929534_70089520');
    3: begin //Step 2 must have finished!
         Js := Concat('aaa = new Object; ',
                      'aaa.Message = function(Msg) ',
                      '{ ',
                      '   alert(Msg); ',
                      '}');
                      //DevTools-->Console: type aaa
                      web.ExecuteScript(Js);

        end;
     else
        begin
          Js := 'aaa.Message("Hallo Welt!")';
          web.ExecuteScript(Js);
        end;
   end;
   STEP := STEP + 1;
 end;
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnm4R.png)
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4B6k.png)

Comment: Thanks @USauter 

The concept code above is exactly what I have been doing to execute a script after navigation is completed.  The script examines the keydown/keypress events.  It seems to work "ok" for the main page.  Once the user starts selecting different tabs (there is no page refresh, navigation complete, document title change) I cannot seem to inject the same JS to the footer of subsequent pages because no event gets generated for me to trap.

I am simply trying to intercet the keypresses  of tedgebrowser so an F12 does not present the window below my window.

Comment: Maybe you have to give something to it. `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
   //your code goes here on location change 
});` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes] looks promising.