# What should be done to make it working in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

This code works well in modern browsers. What should be done to make it working in IE7?

```
function paymentCheck() {
            var obj = {
                            'type' : 'car',
                            'year' : 2008,
                            'make' : 'Dodge',
                            'model' : 'Avenger',
                            'payments' : 'in process',
                            'paid' : 13286,
                            'toBePaid' : 34856,
                            'paymentsLeft' : 24,
            }              

            return (obj.toBePaid - obj.paid) / obj.paymentsLeft;
}

var button = document.getElementById("calcButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert(paymentCheck());
}, false);
```

Comment: Why would anyone care about IE7? Microsoft abandoned it circa 2011 and it has virtually no share of the current browser market ( 0.64% according to wikipedia).

Comment: `addEventListener` does not work on IE7.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.So what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akxe mentioned IE7 does not support the `addEventListener` function. You can check if the browser supports `addEventListener` and if not, use the 
 `attachEvent` instead:

```
// check if the browser supports 'addEventListener'
if(document.addEventListener){ 
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(paymentCheck());
    });
} else {
    button.attachEvent("click", function(){
        alert(paymentCheck());
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

IE7 don't have `addEventListener` function. You should use `attachEvent`, but this is IE8 and less only, other browsers don't support it!
See [MSIE and addEventListener Problem in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript)