# IE 11 Paste only works on Input Fields

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, copy-paste

I need to capture the paste event on a custom grid however in IE11 the Ctrl + V paste event only works on Input Fields. I need it to work on a component and access it via the Window. In Chrome it works perfect.

```
 public ngOnInit() {
   window.addEventListener('paste', myCustomEvent.bind(this));
}
```

In Chrome when user clicks Ctrl+ V anywhere on the screen this fires

```
myCustomEvent(event) {    

    // gets data from clipboard and converts it to an array (1 array element for each line)
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent['clipboardData'].getData('text');
    console.log('event' , event);
    console.log(clipboardData);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695376/msie-and-addeventlistener-problem-in-javascript

Comment: Yea still the same issue. replacing 'onclick' with 'paste' works in Chrome but still not IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a listener event for keydown. When the user presses Ctrl+V it will fire your event. From there you can access the clipBoardData. Dont forget to import Renderer2 into your constructor

```
this.global = this.renderer.listen('document', 'keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey === true && event.key === 'v') {
          const clipboardData = window['clipboardData'].getData('Text');
          if (clipboardData) {
            this.ProcessBeforePaste(clipboardData);
          }
        }
      });
```